# How to find trigonometric/oscillation function in another form?

Tags: calculus

I come across this function, $f(x) = \sin x + \frac{1}{3} \sin3x$ which has a slope of $f'(x) = \cos x + \cos 3x$. The author says, to find the zeros of $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$, rewrite those functions as $$f(x) = 2 \sin x - \frac{4}{3} \sin^3 x$$ This leads to $f'(x)= -2 \cos x+ 4  \cos^3 x$ and $f''(x) = -10 \sin x +12 \sin^3 x$. However, I am not sure why $$\sin x + \frac{1}{3} \sin3x = 2 \sin x - \frac{4}{3} \sin^3$$ How do I rewrite these functions? Relatively, are there infinite functions that are equal to this function?

Comment: Reduction formulas!

Answer (score 0):

---

**Toolkit**

As noted by @Saketh Malyala, use reduction formulas.

[Trigonometric Power Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html)

$$\sin^{3}x = \frac{1}{4} \left( 3 \sin x - \sin 3x \right)$$

[Multiple-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html)

$$\cos (3x) = \cos^{3} x - 3 \cos x \sin^{2} x$$

**Function**

$$
\begin{align}
 f(x) 
&= \sin (x)-\frac{1}{3} \sin (3 x) \\
&= \sin(x)-\sin (x) \cos ^2(x)+\frac{\sin ^3(x)}{3}\\
&= \sin (x) \left( 1 - \cos ^2(x) +\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{3} \right) \\
&= \sin (x) \left( -\frac{2}{3}(\cos (2 x)-1) \right)
\end{align}
$$
For integer $k$, the roots are
$$
%
\begin{align}
 \sin x = 0 \qquad &\Rightarrow \qquad x = k \pi \\
 \cos (2 x)-1 = 0 \qquad &\Rightarrow \qquad x = k \pi \\
%
\end{align}
$$
Plot
$$
f(x) 
= \sin (x)-\frac{1}{3} \sin (3 x)
$$

[image: f]

---

**Derivative**

$$
\begin{align}
 f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} \left( \sin (x)-\frac{1}{3} \sin (3 x) \right) \\
&=\cos (x)-\cos (3 x) \\
&= \cos (x) \left( 1+3 \sin ^2(x)  -\cos ^2(x) \right) \\
&= -\cos (x) \left(1+2 \cos (2 x) \right)
\end{align}
$$

The roots are
$$
%
\begin{align}
 \cos x = 0 \qquad &\Rightarrow \qquad x = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi \\
 1+2 \cos (2 x) = 0 \qquad &\Rightarrow \qquad x = k \pi \\
%
\end{align}
$$

Plot
$$f'(x) = \cos (x)-\cos (3 x)$$

[image: der]

---

**Second derivative**

$$
\begin{align}
 f''(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} f'(x) =  \frac{d}{dx} \left( \cos (x)-\cos (3 x) \right) \\
&=\sin (x) \left(9 \cos ^2(x)-3 \sin ^2(x)-1\right)
\end{align}
$$

The roots are
$$
%
\begin{align}
 \sin x = 0 \qquad &\Rightarrow \qquad x =  k\pi \\
 9 \cos ^2(x)-3 \sin ^2(x)-1 = 0 \qquad &\Rightarrow \qquad x = \pm \arctan \sqrt{2} + k \pi \\
%
\end{align}
$$

Plot
$$
f''(x) = -\sin (x) + 3 \sin (3 x)
$$

[image: der2]